# ASSIGN value for cmd in sysprocesses? What does it mean?

Tags: sql-server, system-tables

We're seeing some strange blocking behaviour in a production (SQL Server 2008 R2) system that we're investigating, and it seems to have one consistent and novel element: in the `sysprocesses` table, the relevant blocking process always has `ASSIGN` as the "cmd" column value.

The process that is actually running is a stored procedure, but `dm_exec_sql_text` doesn't give us any more detail that the stored procedure name - it's quite a complex proc.

We know that this stored procedure does a non-negligible amount of Xml (XQuery) processing, so that seems the most likely source of the `ASSIGN` command, but we're having a hard time understanding exactly what the command is, why it would take a long time, and what it might be "hiding":
For example, could it be that this is generally what happens when using a `SET` statement, where the value being set is a subquery?

For example, is this a way to reproduce the issue?

```
DECLARE @Something Int
SET @Something = (
    SELECT Something
    FROM Somewhere
    WHERE DoSomethingReallySlowAndExpensive(Something) = 1
    )
```

---

UPDATE: I can confirm that this is **not** a way to reproduce the issue - a long-running `ASSIGN` command in sysprocesses must mean something else, something more specific.

The test code above simply shows up as `SELECT`.

---

UPDATE 2: To Aaron Bertrand's point/question, the below is ALSO not a way to reproduce the issue. This code will alternate between being listed as cmd `CONDITIONAL` and cmd `SELECT`. So... what does `ASSIGN` mean??

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_CpuLoad] (@LoopCount BigInt)
    RETURNS Bit
AS
BEGIN 
    WHILE @LoopCount > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @LoopCount -= 1
    END

    RETURN 0
END
GO

DECLARE @Something Int
SET @Something = dbo.fn_CpuLoad(100000000)
GO

DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_CpuLoad]
GO
```

---

UPDATE 3:

We eventually realized we were concentrating on the wrong aspect of the data we had available - the "cmd" value was usually `ASSIGN`, but also sometimes `SELECT`; what was completely consistent was the "waitresource" value, which was always the same value, "TAB: 9:547043060:0 [COMPILE]". When we noticed this, we rapidly found information on compile locks that helped us track down the causes:

- [Microsoft article on compile locks](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/263889), identifying the name-qualification issue that was mainly biting us
- [Another misc article](http://www.pythian.com/blog/sql-server-compile-locking-and-encryption-keys/), about compile locks and encryption, also containing useful info

So we've now addressed the issues we were hunting, but we still have no idea what the `ASSIGN` value for cmd is, so I'll leave this question open in case anyone with the answer stumbles across it.

Comment: Run DBCC INPUTBUFFER (SPID) on an other connection while a transaction is running. This will Display you the last statement sent from client against SPID

Comment: thanks, but we know the statement sent by the client - that is the stored procedure name, reported by `dm_exec_sql_text`, right? Or are you saying that `DBCC INPUTBUFFER` would additionally show us the stored procedure arguments? Or show us actual statements executing WITHIN the stored procedure? To the best of my knowledge neither of those is true, but if it were that would be great. My question about `ASSIGN` is really to help us track down what, within the sproc, is taking so long. We have a hard time getting permission for profiler on production...

Comment: Tao, yes DBCC INPUTBUFFER will show you procedure with arguments in Event Info. First get SP with exact augments then you can figure out exact expensive statement of that SP thorough execution Plan.

Comment: Sp_whoisactive to the rescue. Run it and save the output to table for further analysis. Alternatively, you can use event notification with blocked process report as well.

Comment: How about `SET @something = dbo.ReallyExpensiveScalarFunction();`?

Comment: Thanks @AaronBertrand, but that doesn't seem to be it... any idea where I could look?

Comment: You say you're looking at `sysprocesses`. This is a backward compatibility view that is deprecated. What does `sys.dm_exec_requests` say?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, unfortunately the extraction of that lock-cause information is automated, and (clearly) based on some old SQL Server 2000 code - this is not something we were able to change. We did eventually notice what should have been obvious and addressed our issue, but the actual question about `ASSIGN` remains unanswered.

Comment: You haven't answered my question though - at the time sysprocesses is showing ASSIGN, what is sys.dm_exec_requests showing? This could help solve the question...

Comment: @AaronBertrand - sorry, I tried to: the answer is "I don't know, because the process capturing the data in production could not be changed on-the-fly and I was not able to have someone manually query `sys.dm_exec_requests` at exactly the right time". The obvious answer is "it looks like `sys.sysprocesses.cmd` is the same as `sys.dm_exec_requests.command`", but I have no empirical evidence to support this assumption in this exact situation. If it turns into a question you're happy to answer though, I'd be happy to ask "what does the `command` value `ASSIGN` in `sys.dm_exec_requests` mean?"

Comment: Crap. just realized my query testing for differences was broken, there are a lot of diofferences between the two, and this is likely to be one :) So the other question would likely not make sense.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: and back the other way - the only difference I can find seems to be that sysprocesses includes "AWAITING COMMAND" connections, whereas `sys.dm_exec_requests` only includes connections that are actually executing requests... So yeah, feel free to reinterpret my question as "`ASSIGN` value for `command` in `sys.dm_exec_requests`? What does it mean?"